# file not found in running shell script through python

Tags: python, shell

I have a python script, in a single part of code, have to execute a terminal command this is code:

```
# run shell script and return response printed
def run_shell(command_string):
    p = subprocess.Popen([command_string], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
    return p.communicate()
```

it's  the certain function that gets a command and runs that. for example when input is "find" (to list files and dirs recursively) output is:

```
./actions
./actions/scripts
./actions/scripts/script_aa00.py
./log_list_template.json
./README.md
./.git
./main
./main/Classifier.py
./main/Solver.py
./main/learner.py
./main/Database.py
./main/__pycache__
./main/__pycache__/Database.cpython-35.pyc
./main/__pycache__/learner.cpython-35.pyc
./start.sh
./run.py
./signals
./signals/scripts
./signals/scripts/script_aa00.py  [I want to run this script]
./signals/list0.json
./signals/template.json
```

but when input is "**python3 signals/scripts/script_aa00.py**" output contains an error that means script_aa00.py not found. when i try "**python3 signals/scripts/script_aa00.py**" myself in terminal (in this dir) works fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try to add `shell=true` to Popen and/or use absolute paths:

```
p = subprocess.Popen(['/usr/bin/python3', '/home/.../signals/scripts/script_aa00.py'], shell=true, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, ...)
```